# Access to Javascript variable after it was initialized by ViewBag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is action function:

```
public ActionResult TranslatorForm()
{
    string[] arrDepartment = new string[]{"Engeneering","Science","Mediciene"};

    ViewBag.Department = arrDepartment;
    return PartialView("TranslatorFormPartial");
}
```

Here is JQuery function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var departments = "@ViewBag.Department";
 });
```

As you can see I store the passed data from the sever **ViewBag.Department** in departments javascript variable.At some point I want to create drop-down list and populate it using data in departments variable.

But I don't  how to access to the elements in departments javascript variable.
Any Idea how can I implement it?
Any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the `ViewBag` property to a javascript array using

```
var departments = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Department))');
```

then you can access it with a normal loop or using a jquery `.each()` function, for example

```
for (i = 0; i < departments.length; i++) { 
    var dept = departments[0]; // returns `Engeneering`
}
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why `JSON.parse` a string instead of `var departments = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Department));`?

Comment: @RGraham. Without the `JSON.parse` then `var dept = departments[0]` would return `[` and `departments[1]` would return `"` and `departments[2]` would return `E` (it would be just an array of characters)

Comment: But `Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Department))` would output `["Engeneering","Science","Mediciene"]` surely as you've JSON.encoded a `string[]`?

Comment: @RGraham. If you check the output using `typeof` then without `JSON.parse` it will return `string` (so a `for` loop will just access each character) but with `JSON.parse` it will return object which is an array (in OP' case, containing 3 objects)

Comment: Yes, it returns a string, but it's a JSON string so it's just a Javascript subset so if you print that out *raw* it's just a JS array - See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZJZxZn

Comment: OK, I see now. Didn't spot it at first but the difference is the single quotes around the `'@Html.Raw(...))'` in mine verses none in yours

Comment: Stephen, what if I want to pass object?How can I display properties of the passed object in for example in alert window?

Comment: @Michael, If you assign (say) typeof `Person` to `ViewBag.Person` and `Person` contains property `FirstName`, then `var person = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Person))');` and to access the value of `FirstName`, then `var firstName = person.FirstName;`

Comment: But why I have to encode  in Json format ViewBag.Person?I have some misunderstanding about this this topic.Can you give me some internet links to read?

Comment: @Michael, The browser has no knowledge of what a C# class is. So your class needs to be serialized into a format which the browser can understand and work with (javascript/json), which is what the method does.

Answer (score 1):

You can output the departments as a string:

```
string departments = "Engeneering,Science,Mediciene";
ViewBag.Department = departments;
```

And in your view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var departments = '@ViewBag.Department'.split(',');
});
```

Now your departments JS variable should be an array of departments.